# Is $R[x]/(g) \cong R[x]^{n-1}$ as groups, where $g$ is monic of degree $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, group-isomorphism

I am trying a problem that asks if it is true that $R[x]/(g) \cong R[x]^{(n-1)}$ (as groups under addition), when $g$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$, and where $(g)$ is the ideal generated by $g$. Note, $R[x]^{(n)} = \{f \in R[x] : \deg(f) \leq n\}$ and $R$ is a commutative ring.

I know if $g = x^n$, this statement holds intuitively. Though, if $g = x^n + x + 1$ or any other polynomial with more than one term, I'm not so sure.

My hunch is that it is true and I would like to try and apply the first isomorphism theorem, but I cannot find a group homomorphism with kernel $(g)$, given that I believe $(g)$ can be irreducible.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: You mean $R^n$??

Comment: I actually don't. The problem in the book is stated as I described. I added a sentence to clear up the notation $R[x]^{(n-1)}$. Let me know if that doesn't make sense!

Comment: Well, that is a peculiar notation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $R[x]^{(n-1)}\to R[x]/(g)$ that is induced by the inclusion is injective and onto.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the map is onto? Better yet, if you could help me with an example to see: setting $g = x^2 + x + 1$, how do we know $x^2$ or $x^2 + 1$ are not in the set of representatives of $R[x]/(x^2 + x + 1)$?

Comment: Apply the fact $R[x]$ is a Euclidean ring: for any $p \in R[x]$, $p = qg + r$ with $\deg r < \deg g$. So if $g \mid p$....

Comment: $R[x]$ need not be a Euclidean ring (consider $R=\Bbb Z$) but the division algorithm works for monic polynomials over any commutative ring.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!